# ASP.NET WebForms FriendlyUrls File / Folder conflict

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, friendly-url

I'm facing a problem with Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls. I have a page with user management, so the user can edit his own profile and so on.. I want the URLS to be like this:

- somesite.com/User          (Users Dashboard)
- somesite.com/User/Profile (Users Profile)

Now having a page named User.aspx and a folder named User with a page named Profile.aspx in it causes Problems. The Folder gets prioritized and i get HTTP Error 403.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found an answer for my question.
Its really simple actually. I just placed the User.aspx file into the User folder and renamed it to default.aspx that works. :)